# Derive dual problem for this optimization problem without using conjugate function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

In Example 5.5 of the book [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), the authors derived the dual problem for the optimization problem

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{min} && \log \sum_i^m \exp y_i\\
& \text{s.t.} && Ax + b = y
\end{aligned}
$$

where $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}, x \in \mathbb R^n, b, y \in \mathbb R^m$, using the conjugate function of log-sum-exp. (The derivation can be found [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) at page 268)

My question is, is it possible for us to derive the dual problem without using the conjugate function?

The following is my current attempt:

The Lagrangian is

$$L(x, y, v) = \log \sum_i^m \exp y_i + v^T(Ax + b - y)$$

where $v \in \mathbb R^m$ is the Lagrange multiplier.

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = A^Tv = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{\sum_i^m \exp y_i}
\left(\begin{array}{c} \exp y_1 \\ \exp y_2 \\ . \\ . \\ . \\  \exp y_m \end{array}\right) 
- v = 0$$

So we have

$$A^T v = 0$$

$$\frac{\exp y_i}{\sum_j^m \exp y_j} = v_i \ \ \forall i$$

I've also noticed that the second equation implies that $\textbf 1^T v = 1$ and $v \succeq 0$.

Here's where I get stuck. I don't know how to continue to express the dual function.

Comment: So far, you've found a bunch of implicit constraints on the dual variables (the inf of L(x,y,v) will be unbounded unless $1^{T}v=1$, $v\geq 0$, and $A^{T}v=0$.  These will end up as dual constraints.  Assuming they're satisfied, what is the inf?

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes I realized that these constraints are dual constraints, but I don’t know how to express the $\inf$ because I can’t solve for $y$ :(. Mind giving me more hint?

Comment: The hint here is that you don't have to solve for $y$.  Rather, you need to find the value of $-v^{T}y+v^{T}b+\log(\sum e^{y_{i}})$ in terms of $v$ at a value of $y$ that satisfies the constraints.

Comment: Here's the thing: you say you're not using the conjugate function, but in fact you're effectively doing the same computations you would use to _derive_ the conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints and guidance given by @BrianBorchers and @MichaelGrant, I've figured out the answer. I am posting it here so it might help others.

From

$$\frac{\exp y_i}{\sum_j^m \exp y_j} = v_i \ \ \forall i$$

we can easily express $y_i$ as

$$y_i = \log v_i \sum_j^m \exp y_j$$

Substitute this and $A^Tv = 0$ into the Lagrangian, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
&& L(y, v) &= \log\sum_i^m \exp y_i + b^Tv - \sum_i^mv_i( \log v_i \sum_j^m \exp y_j)\\
&&& = \log\sum_i^m \exp y_i + b^Tv - \sum_i^mv_i( \log v_i  + \log\sum_j^m \exp y_j)\\
&&& = \log\sum_i^m \exp y_i + b^Tv - \sum_i^mv_i \log v_i - \log\sum_j^m \exp y_j\sum_i^m v_i\\
&& & = b^Tv- \sum_i^mv_i\log v_i \\
&&& = g(v)
\end{aligned}$$

With the dual function in place we can proceed to write out the dual problem:

$$\begin{aligned}
& \text{max} && b^Tv - \sum_i^m v_i \log v_i\\
& \text{s.t.} && A^Tv = 0\\
&&& \textbf 1^Tv = 1\\
&&& v \succeq 0
\end{aligned}$$

As @MichaelGrant pointed out, the steps above are effectively deriving the conjugate function.